# Why won't my simple get request with axios return what the controller's returning?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, debugging

I'm learning Laravel with React.js but I can't figure out why my simple get request won't work. I get a `404` error.  I've seen a similar question asked on SO and I've tried running `composer require barryvdh/laravel-cors` on the command line but it still doesn't work.

How can I rectify this?

Here's react code:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.axiosGet = this.axiosGet.bind(this);
}

axiosGet(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios.get('/thank-you')
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
        });
}

render() {
    <Form onSubmit={this.axiosGet}>
    ...
    </Form> 
}
```

Here's `api.php`

```
use App\Http\Controllers\MailController;

Route::get('/thank-you', [MailController::class,'index']);
```

Here's `MailController.php`

```
public function index() {
    return "Testing";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your route is `/api/thank-you`. When you are using API routes. API comes in front of your routes.

Change your `axios.get('/thank-you')` as `axios.get('/api/thank-you')`